# Python KIVY: recursive DropDown

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown

I would like to create a DropDown that contains 3 other DropDowns that contains 3 buttons each.

I would like the first DropDown to open three more DropDowns, when we click on one of them, three buttons appear, and in any case when a button appears, which is below down without display bug. When you click on a dropdown for se second time, it hides its children widgets.

I'm using this way to create a dropdown:

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    button_text = StringProperty('Show possibilities')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDown(self)

    def open_drop_down(self, widget):            
        self.dropdown.open(widget)

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = screen_manager

    def on_select(self, data):
        self.sm.button_text = data

Builder.load_file("debug.kv")

class MyAppli(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

.kv:

```
<MyScreenManager>:

    MyScreen:

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'top'

            Button:

                text: root.button_text
                size:(200,50)
                size_hint:(None,None)
                on_release: root.open_drop_down(self)

<CustomDropDown>:
    Button:
        text:"Item 1"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select("ONE")
    Button:
        text:"Item 2"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        text:"Item 3"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        on_release: root.select("THREE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another custom drop down class and adding a button method to open/dismiss the second drop down. The `open_drop2()` method does the open/dismiss. Added `padding` to each `Button` in an attempt to show the cascading a bit. Additional cascading can be done using the same scheme, i.e., add a `CustomDropDown3` class that is opened by a button in `CustomDropDown2`. Note that the `dismiss_on_select: False` in the kv file is required to be sure that the `is2Displayed` attribute is updated correctly.

.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    button_text = StringProperty('Show possibilities')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDown1(self)

    def open_drop_down(self, widget):
        self.dropdown.open(widget)

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class CustomDropDown1(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = screen_manager
        self.dropdown2 = CustomDropDown2(self.sm)
        self.is2Displayed = False

    def on_select(self, data):
        self.sm.button_text = data

    def open_drop2(self):
        if not self.is2Displayed:
            self.dropdown2.open(self)
            self.is2Displayed = True
        else:
            self.dropdown2.dismiss()
            self.is2Displayed = False

class CustomDropDown2(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = screen_manager

    def on_select(self, data):
        self.sm.button_text = data

Builder.load_file("debug.kv")

class MyAppli(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyAppli().run()
```

.kv:

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    MyScreen:
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: root.button_text
                size: (200, 50)
                size_hint:(None,None)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1.0}
                on_release: root.open_drop_down(self)

<CustomDropDown1>:
    padding: [0,0,0,0]
    Button:
        text:"Item 1"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (10,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        text:"Item 2"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (10,0)
        on_release: root.open_drop2()
    Button:
        text:"Item 3"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (10,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)

<CustomDropDown2>:
    dismiss_on_select: False
    Button:
        text:"Item 1,2"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (50,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        text:"Item 2,2"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (50,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        text:"Item 3,2"
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (50,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When I run your code and click item 2, the second dropdown appears below item3. Is it possible to make the second dropdown appear below its parent (item 2) and push item 3 down ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible using DropDown. DropDown is a pretty simple subclass of GridLayout and does not have many embellishments. If you want to do something fancier, you could eliminate the use of DropDown and just add/remove buttons from your main screen in your Python code.